# How to use Spring AMQP with Spring Cloud Microservice

Tags: jhipster, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-netflix

I used JHipster to generate a several microservices based on Spring Cloud Netflix. Currently thinking about adding Spring AMQP support in one of the services, using this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

When adding the AMQP support in the services, I found the service always register with the Registry(Eureka) server with status DOWN, and if i remove following gradle dependency the problem will go away

```
    compile('org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.5.3.RELEASE')
```

The services with this dependency will first register with Eureka server with status UP at start up time, and then immediately re-register with status DOWN.

[eureka registry server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcnU1.png)

**The logs of Eureka server:**

> 2016-08-26 06:55:18.291  INFO 5875 --- [io-8761-exec-11] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status STARTING (replication=false)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:18.806  INFO 5875 --- [io-8761-exec-10] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status STARTING (replication=true)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:21.260  INFO 5875 --- [nio-8761-exec-8] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status STARTING (replication=false)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:21.763  INFO 5875 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status STARTING (replication=true)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:37.220  INFO 5875 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status UP (replication=false)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:37.730  INFO 5875 --- [nio-8761-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status UP (replication=true)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:37.885  INFO 5875 --- [io-8761-exec-11] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status DOWN (replication=false)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:38.399  INFO 5875 --- [nio-8761-exec-5] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance SALES/sales:4454c0adc6b9c70d799930ac3b7d374c with status DOWN (replication=true)
>   2016-08-26 06:55:43.699  INFO 5875 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 2ms
>   2016-08-26 06:56:43.700  INFO 5875 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 2ms

**On the other side, the log of the Sales service does not have any errors. however comparing with other services which do not have amqp dependency, the most significant difference in the log is**

> 2016-08-26 06:55:37.881  WARN 6440 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Ignoring onDemand update due to rate limiter

I confirmed the issue will be fixed if i remove the spring amqp dependency.

Am I using the wrong amqp dependency? Is there any other way to use RabbitMQ in spring cloud microservices?

Answer (score 1):

1. In spring boot, when you add starter dependency like
   spring-amqp-starter,the framework will automatically configure the
   related properties to their default values.
2. Discovery server such as Eureka use the URL
   (http://{service-ip}:{service-port}/health) to check the service
   health(availability),both ip and port are provided to Eureka during
   the deployment of the service, a call from service is done to the
   server to register itself.
3. Here comes the trick, if your rabbit MQ server is not up and running
   on the configured IP or port,the response of health check will be
   "DOWN".

Conclusion : make sure that rabbit server up and running and any other components with thier dependencies in the class path(Redis, Couchbase and so on) and use the URL (http://{service-ip}:{service-port}/health) to check your service health, you should get something like this :

{
  "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client",
  "status": "UP"
}